# How to give a space along with printing result

Tags: python-3.x, string, integer

So, i want to create a function. If i use 4 as input number, then it will give a result:

```
****
 ***
  **
   *
```

I use code like this.

```
def print_pattern(input_number):
    for i in reversed(range(input_number)):
        integer = (i+1)
        if integer == input_number:
            output = (integer * '*')
        elif integer < input_number:
            output = " " + (integer * '*')
        print(output)

print_pattern(6)
```

But, the result only show the first looping like this.

```
****
 ***
 **
 *
```

what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str.rjust`

**Ex:**

```
def print_pattern(input_number):
    num = input_number+1
    for i in reversed(range(num)):
        print(("*"*i).rjust(input_number, " "))


print_pattern(4)
```

**Output:**

```
****
 ***
  **
   *
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def print_pattern(input_number):
    for i in range(input_number):
        print((" " * i) + "*" * (input_number -i))
```

Examples:

```
>>> print_pattern(4)
****
 ***
  **
   *
>>> print_pattern(6)
******
 *****
  ****
   ***
    **
     *
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It really helps.